# How to move data between hadoop clusters

Tags: hadoop

I have 2 hadoop clusters running on VMs. How do I move HDFS data between those clusters.
I can scp the data on HDFS, how about metadata that sits on Data nodes ?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Look at DistCp.  It's a [part of hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp.html) that does inter/intra cluster copying of data.